Geometric calculations, path search
In a rectangle with a length of 2a and a width of a, cut out n non-overlapping circles with a radius of r=1 and find the minimum value of a.
Requirements and goals:
Place n circles of radius 1 without overlapping in a 2D rectangular region with an aspect ratio of 2:1. Design an algorithm with the lowest possible time complexity to find the minimum value (optimal or approximately optimal) of the rectangular range. It is required to be able to find the width an of the rectangle with n in the range [1,100]
According to the requirements of the topic, carry out algorithm design and analysis, complete program compilation, and provide specific test cases and test results.
The following is my solution using Java. The main idea is hexagonal arrangement. I don't know if it is correct. I hope someone can help me check it out.
import java.util.*;

public class CirclePacking {
private static final double RADIUS = 1.0;


private static boolean canPlaceCircles(int n, double a) {
    double width = 2 * a;  
    double height = a;     

    int rows = 1;
    int circlesInRow = 0;

    
    while (n > 0) {
        if (rows % 2 != 0) {
            
            circlesInRow = (int) (width  / (2 * RADIUS));
        } else {
            
            circlesInRow = (int) ((width - RADIUS) / (2 * RADIUS));
        }
        n -= circlesInRow;

        if (rows == 1) {
            height -= 2 * RADIUS;  
        } else {
            height -= Math.sqrt(3) * RADIUS;  
        }

        if (height < 0) {
            return false;  
        }
        rows++;
    }

    return true;  
}


public static double findMinimumWidth(int n) {
    double left = 1.0;  
    double right = n * 2.0;  

    while (right - left > 1e-6) {
        double mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (canPlaceCircles(n, mid)) {
            right = mid;
        } else {
            left = mid;
        }
    }
    return right;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of circles: ");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    double minimumWidth = findMinimumWidth(n);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("The minimum width a is: " + minimumWidth);
    System.out.println(endTime-startTime);
}

}

I'm sorry ，actually I have already done it in Java, but I think there is no way to verify whether I did it right, so I post it here. Can you help me? Thanks a lot

Sure, please post the code you have, together with the results you obtained and why you think it's not good. Veryfying the solution for small n values should be easy. And tag the question as java

OK, I have made the changes

I don't understand the logic of what you do. You iterate for each n? You need to determine for a given n how many rows you have and then the tricky part would be to determine how much overlap between rows you have. Here's an example with 11 circles https://imgur.com/a/v4b71w9  but for some values of n the circles in the same row don;t touch, so the overlap with the next row will be higher or lower depending on n.
